# Google Chrome Extension Over HTTPS doesn't work.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have created my first extension for Google Chrome but doesn't work over https however I have putting the permission of https urls in manifest file what is my problem.

```
{

"name": "My first extension",

"version": "1.0",

"manifest_version": 2,


"description": "My Chrome Extension is a free extension.",



   "icons": {"16": "IrsiIcon16.png",
"48": "IrsiIcon48.png",
"128": "IrsiIcon128.png"
  },


       "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "IrsiIcon128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },


 "permissions": [
        "tabs",
         "*://*/*", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],


"content_scripts":
  [{"matches": ["*://*/*","http://*/*", "https://*/*"],"js": ["jquery.js", "actions.js"],   
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to send request over https?
Your manifest is OK. Maybe you have an another problem?

Comment: I have one JavaScript file called actions.js may be have an error

Comment: So, if you don't debug your code, no one do this for you. Open devtools and say what you see!

Comment: At console mode this error appear (  Mixed Content: The page at 'https//exampledomain.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint . This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. )